# Python - 4 in a row matrix - varables dont change

Tags: python, list, matrix

As you probably know in 4 in a row you need to have 4 same coins in a row. Coins are represented by 1 and 2. 0 is just a placeholder so no one onw if a row of multiple zeros exists. So I finished my code to go trough the matrix vertically. Now whats left is horizontally and diagonally. But I am having a hard time finishing my vertical code. I debugged it and rewrote it multiple times but I cant get it working. That is my working code it goes trough the matrix vertically.

```
# using this matrix to test
# I know this is not a possible cobination in 4 in a row
# but its easier to test like that
matrix = [
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1],
]
```

```
def WhoWon(self, matrix = True):
    if matrix == True:
        matrix = self.matrix
    for line in matrix:
        last = 0
        count = 0
        for x in line:
            isPlayer = x == 1 or x == 2
            if isPlayer and last == x:
                count += 1
                if count == 4:
                    return x
            elif isPlayer:
                count = 1
                last = x
            else:
                count = 0
                last = 0
```

Here is my code for vertically going trough matrix(it seems like last does not change for some reason):

```
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    for i2 in range(len(matrix)):
        last = 0
        count = 0
        x = matrix[i2][i]
        isPlayer = x == 1 or x == 2
        if isPlayer and last == x:
            count += 1
            if count == 4:
                return x
        elif isPlayer:
            count = 1
            last = x
        else:
            count = 0
            last = 0
```

So maybe someone can help me and I also have no idea how to go trough matrix diagonally so ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to begin with... I think if you use `numpy.ndarray` or `numpy.matrix` it would be a lot easier reading the data row- column- diagonal- wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem you are having with the vertical: you set the `last` and `count` to `0` when you get the next value of the column. This should work:

```
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    last = 0  #only reset when starting next column
    count = 0 #only reset when starting next column
    for i2 in range(len(matrix)):
        # last = 0  #< delete it here
        # count = 0 #< delete it here
        x = matrix[i2][i]
        isPlayer = x == 1 or x == 2
        if isPlayer and last == x:
            count += 1
            if count == 4:
                return x
        elif isPlayer:
            count = 1
            last = x
        else:
            count = 0
            last = 0
```

And in general: python is great, but not great with matrices on its own. You always have a list of lists. So I would also recommend you to look into `numpy` as @Alireza suggested. It makes this work much easier!

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your matrix is not square (6x7) so I dont know how you can check the diagonal. but is you want to check all the rows,columns,diag
you can do something like;

```py
import numpy as np
mat = np.asarray(matrix)
diag = mat.diagonal()
row_i = mat[i,:]
col_i = mat[:,i]
```

Comment: sorry I did not mean diagonal but rather from top left down as far as possible and then from top second left as far down as possible so often till its no more more then 4 ints there like @AfiJaab said but thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your code the variable last doesn't change since in each iteration of the second for loop you are declaring `last = 0`.So each time your assign a value to `last` it looses this value once it moves to the next iteration.Arranging it like this should probably work.

```
for i in range(len(matrix[0])):
    last = 0
    count = 0
    for i2 in range(len(matrix)):       
        x = matrix[i2][i]
        isPlayer = x == 1 or x == 2
        if isPlayer and last == x:
            count += 1
            if count == 4:
                return x
        elif isPlayer:
            count = 1
            last = x
        else:
            count = 0
            last = 0
```

To check if there are four consecutive elements diagonally you can try to use the following code.This iterates through the whole matrix diagonally downwards to the right and then to the left.You might want to make some changes to make it suit your script.

```
for i in range(len(matrix[0])-3):
    for i2 in range(len(matrix)-3):
        if matrix[i2][i] == matrix[i2+1][i+1] == matrix[i2+2][i+2] == matrix[i2+3][i+3]:
            return matrix[i2][i]

for i in range(3, len(matrix[0])):
    for i2 in range(len(matrix)-3):
        if matrix[i2][i] == matrix[i2-1][i-1] == matrix[i2-2][i-2] == matrix[i2-3][i-3]:
            return matrix[i2][i]
```